# Magento 1.9.3.9 PayFlow API - Multiple Issues

Tags: magento-1.9, api, admin-user, paypal-payflow-pro

I can't find a solution to this anywhere so I'm posting the very strange issues I'm having, in hopes that someone has an answer.

I've been going back and forth with PayPal support because I keep getting the error: "PayPal gateway rejected the request. User authentication failed" when clicking the "Pay with PayPal" button on my site and they're telling me a few things that don't make sense:

1. In the file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Payflowpro.php it is referencing the correct URLS: https://payflowpro.paypal.com for live, and https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com for testing.
2. My [USER] => field is not passing, according to PayPal support. I have triple-checked my user credentials in System + Configuration + Payment Methods + PayPal Payment Gateways + Payflow Pro after temporarily changing the "obscure" fields to "text" so I can see what the database holds for my credentials in the /home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/system.xml file. What I have matches what's in my Payflow Manager account.
3. In the shopping cart, PayPal does not show "Pay with Credit Card", only "Pay with Paypal" as an option. According to PayPal tech support, since I'm using Payflow Pro Gateway I should be seeing a "Pay with Credit Card" option as well.

Here's what I see in the error log (replacing my directory with 'mydir'):

exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal gateway errors: User authentication failed.' in /home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/PaypalUk/Model/Api/Nvp.php:505
Stack trace:
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1009): Mage_PaypalUk_Model_Api_Nvp->_handleCallErrors(Array)
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(617): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('SetExpressCheck...', Array)
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(381): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callSetExpressCheckout()
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(108): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->start('https://new.domain...', 'https://new.domain...', true)
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->startAction()
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('start')
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/home/mydir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/home/mydir/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/home/mydir/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')

My Magento install is using the popular PORTO theme.

I'm having the same problem on 2 different servers, so it isn't isolated.

Does anyone on planet earth have any ideas?

Thank you!

MB